# vuejs v-model directive does not update toggle of Konsta UI Toggle Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use a Konsta UI Toggle element. It does not accept the v-model directive.

```
    <script setup lang="ts">

    import { kPage, kBlock, kButton, kToggle } from 'konsta/vue';
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const checked = ref(false);

    </script>

    <template>
      <k-page>
        <k-block class="space-y-4"    >
          <p>:checked: {{ checked }}</p>
          <k-toggle :checked="checked" @change="() => checked = !checked" />

        </k-block>

        <k-block class="space-y-4">
          <p>v-model: {{ checked }}</p>
          <k-toggle v-model="checked" />
        </k-block>

        <k-block class="space-y-4">
          <p>checkbox: {{ checked }}</p>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" />
        </k-block>
      </k-page>
      
    </template>
```

The second toggle is based on v-model, but it is not working as expected. The first Toggle is what is seen in the example that I followed, but I expect the second to work because it is a compact form based on v-model.

Comment: Does the first `<k-toggle` work with `<input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" />`? it should, so use that

Comment: @Jaromanda X No, it doesn't.

Comment: that's odd, so the `<p>` above that doesn't change content? i.e. `<p>:checked: {{ checked }}</p>` - and I don't mean when you toggle `<k-toggle v-model="checked" />` since konsta/vue seems to be poorly written and does not use `v-model` ... i.e. the first and third "checkboxes" do "synchronise"

Comment: @Jaromanda The first toggle and checkbox are in sync. The second toggle neither responds for clicks nor updates it's state when checked changes value.

Comment: exactly, because, as you say, k-block do NOT use v-model, so adding v-model attribute does nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to use `v-model` correctly with the `k-toggle` component, you can create a custom component that wraps around `k-toggle` and handles the `v-model` directive properly. Here's how you can do it:

```
<template>
  <k-toggle :checked="innerValue" @change="$emit('input', !innerValue)" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { kToggle } from 'konsta/vue';
import { ref, defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: Boolean
});

const innerValue = ref(props.modelValue);

</script>
```

And then use it in the parent component as follows:

```
<template>
 <k-page>
  <k-block class="space-y-4">
   <p>v-model: {{ checked }}</p>
   <CustomToggle v-model="checked" />
  </k-block>
 </k-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import CustomToggle from './CustomToggle.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const checked = ref(false);
</script>
```

**EDITED -  TypeScript Code Example:**

```
<!-- CustomToggle.vue -->
<template>
  <k-toggle :checked="innerValue" @change="handleChange" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, defineEmits, ref } from 'vue';
import { kToggle } from 'konsta/vue';

const props = defineProps({
 modelValue: {
  type: Boolean,
  required: true
 }
});

const emit = defineEmits();

const innerValue = ref(props.modelValue);

const handleChange = (newValue: boolean) => {
 innerValue.value = newValue;
 emit('update:modelValue', newValue);
};
</script>
```

Then, you can use this custom toggle component in your parent component like this:

```
<template>
  <k-page>
    <k-block class="space-y-4">
      <p>v-model: {{ checked }}</p>
      <CustomToggle v-model="checked" />
    </k-block>
  </k-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import CustomToggle from './CustomToggle.vue';

const checked = ref(false);
</script>
```

Comment: I was looking for a simpler solution in the lines of <q-toggle v-model="value" /> as in https://quasar.dev/vue-components/toggle/. The first toggle is working, but a shorter version using v-model was expected.

Comment: I read their documentation and unfortunately I don't think v-model works directly on k-toggle.